# Oracle BIEE server unable to start on VirtualBox

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, obiee

I have an error when i try to start the Oracle BI server on Oracle VM VirtualBox. I am currently using SampleAppv607p-appliance.

This is my error.

```
/Servers/AdminServer/ListenPort=7001
Accessing admin server using URL t3://demo.us.oracle.com:7001
Starting AdminServer …
Admin Server Start Exception: Error occurred while performing nmStart : Error Starting server AdminServer : Received error message from Node Manager Server: [Server start command for WebLogic server ‘AdminServer’ failed due to: [Server failed to start up but Node Manager was not aware of the reason]. Please check Node Manager log and/or server ‘AdminServer’ log for detailed information.]. Please check Node Manager log for details.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
Reading domain…
/Servers/AdminServer/ListenPort=7001
Accessing admin server using URL t3://demo.us.oracle.com:7001
Requesting credentials …
Enter Weblogic login details at prompt
```

Please do help me. Thank you!

Comment: Well, did you check the Node Manager log/AdminServer log? What did it say?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, your database is probably not up. So confirm the Oracle DB in VM is up and start BI services.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs it looks like you're starting the WebLogic Admin Server via the Node Manager. However, during startup of the Admin Server it prompts for the username/password of domain user (e.g. weblogic) but Node Manager is not passing anything.

To solve this, go to `$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security` and create `boot.properties` file. Edit the file and enter the username and password on separate lines. The username/password was defined upon domain creation, so make sure you know what these values are. See example below:

```
username=weblogic
password=welcome123
```

Start the Admin Server again. This will automatically encrypt the contents of your `boot.properties` file.

It always helps if you check the logs, as they provide more information on the error. In this case, you can check the following logs at the `$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/logs/` directory.